# Mask out a circle/shape when drawing on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, android-canvas

I'm within the onDraw(canvas)  function and so have access to the canvas

I am able to draw the color On the canvas, but I'm trying to mask out (remove/cutout) circles (or any shape) so that the circle can see through the canvas to the layer below:

```
 val pt     = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
 pt.color   = Color.WHITE
 pt.style   = Paint.Style.FILL
 pt.setXfermode(PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST))
 canvas.drawCircle(30,30,10,pt)
```

I have used all the Mode.XXXX available and tried WHITE,BLACK and TRANSPARENT

Any ideas ?
     (added) Needing to support API 19   thanks

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Canvas#clipOutPath(Path)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipOutPath(android.graphics.Path)) method for that.

Like this:

```
canvas.clipOutPath(Path().also {
  it.addCircle(30, 30, 20, Path.Direction.CW)
})
```

For API levels below 26 use:

```
canvas.clipPath(Path().also {
  it.addCircle(30, 30, 20, Path.Direction.CW)
}, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE)
```

Comment: That's a great solution  But it requires API 26 and I'm needing to support API 19  Thanks Sirius do you know of an API 19 method ?

Comment: Updated the answer.